# What does 'Can you tell us about a time you had to close a particularly challenging deal' mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

1. I can't understand the meaning of had to close a deal.
2. Does 'time' has other meaning in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Close a/the deal is an idiom.

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+a+deal), it means:

> To reach an agreement with another party, thus concluding negotiations. We need to move in a month, so how quickly can you close a deal and get our house sold? After months of negotiating, I hired a high-powered attorney to finally close the deal.

Had in this context is the past of **must**.

For example:

> You must (have to) close the deal. (present)
>
> You had to close the deal. (past).
>
> Sooner or later you will have to close the deal. (future).

Time in this context is a particular event, an instance, a moment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A deal is a formal agreement. If you close it, you successfully complete it. In other words, you reach an agreement with another party, thus concluding negotiations:

> Now it was time to close the deal.
>
> After months of negotiating, I hired a high-powered attorney to finally close the deal.
>
> We need your signature to close the deal.

In your sentence, they had to close they deal. = They needed to reach the agreement.

A time is an occasion.

So, I can rephrase your sentence like this:

> Can you tell us about an occasion on which you needed to reach a particularly challenging deal.